# How to consume api in the server side with $resource in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I try using `$resource` in angularjs to consume the api in the server side. Indeed I make it work like this.

```
  app.factory("LevelSettings", ["$resource", function($resource) {
    return $resource("/api/level_setting/list");
  }])
  .factory("LevelSetting", ["$resource", function($resource) {
    return $resource("/api/level_setting/get");
  }])
  .factory("DeleteLevelSettings", ["$resource", function($resource) {
    return $resource("/api/level_setting/delete");
  }])
  .factory("LevelSettingOperation", ["$resource", function($resource) {
    return $resource("/api/level_setting/add_edit");
  }])
```

But I think there can be better way to achieve this. I know some better practice like creating restful api in the server side, but how to consume this restful api in my angularjs client? Or I can just create a service to collect the apis to consume same model like this `level_setting`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, that I understand Your question correctly, but I think, You need make one service for `Level` api. Something like this:

```
angular.module("app.LevelApi", []).factory('LevelApi', ["$resource", function($resource) {
    return {
        'list': listFn,
        'get': getFn,
        'delete': deleteFn,
        'add': addFn
    };

    function listFn() {
        return $resource("/api/level_setting/list");
    };
    function getFn() {
        return $resource("/api/level_setting/get");
    };
    function deleteFn() {
        return $resource("/api/level_setting/delete");
    };

    function addFn() {
        return $resource("/api/level_setting/add_edit");
    };
}]);
```

And use it in controller:

```
app.controller('ctrl',
[       'LevelApi',
function(LevelApi) {
    var list = LevelApi.list();

    function deleteList(){
        LevelApi.delete();
    };

    //... etc

}]);
```